# Get values of input fields from multiple divs with same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get values of input fields within 3 different divs having same class name. Here are the codes:

```js
$('.resultsbtn').click(function() {
    $('.items-block').each(function() {

        var text1 = $(this).('.text1').val();
        var text2 = $(this).('.text2').val();
        var text3 = $(this).('.text3').val();

       code = ' | '+ text1 +', '+ text2 +', '+ text3;
    });
    
    $('.results > span').html( code );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">The Results are: <span></span></div>

<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>

<button class="resultsbtn">View Results</button>
```

This is returning the value of the first div only, whereas it supposed to return the values of all three divs in the format of `var code`. The last two divs are actually clones of the first one, but should that really matter as I am getting the values on click after the divs are cloned and loaded in the DOM.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to declare and initialize a variable outside of the loop that you can add to inside the loop, hence `var code = '';`. Otherwise, you might have a scope issue with a variable declared in the loop.

Secondly, when you wrote `$(this).('.text1').val()` you probably meant to write `$(this).find('.text1').val();` and `$(this).('.text1').val()` has no meaning.

And, finally, in order not to overwrite values already put in the variable you want to use `+=` instead of `=`. In other words: `code = code + ...` instead of `code = ....`.

```js
$('.resultsbtn').click(function() {
    //Declare and initialize variable
    var code = '';
    $('.items-block').each(function() {
        //get values
        var text1 = $(this).find('.text1').val();
        var text2 = $(this).find('.text2').val();
        var text3 = $(this).find('.text3').val();
        //append values to previous to variable -- +=
        code += ' | '+ text1 +', '+ text2 +', '+ text3;
    });
    //output result
    $('.results > span').html( code );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">The Results are: <span></span></div>

<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>

<button class="resultsbtn">View Results</button>
```

Comment: It would be even more helpful to include an explanation of the problem and your solution.

Comment: Updated. Thanks! I had included some comments but it does make sense to explain too.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search for and retrieve the inputs.

Also, define code outside the `each` scope.

Finally note your initial implementation will work for only the last set of input boxes as the iteration will set the singular results element to the last input values.

To overcome, make a set of `result` elements for each group and you can set the result within the `each` itself

```
$('.resultsbtn').click(function() {

        $('.items-block').each(function() {

            var text1 = $(this).find('.text1').val();
            var text2 = $(this).find('.text2').val();
            var text3 = $(this).find('.text3').val();

           var code = ' | '+ text1 +', '+ text2 +', '+ text3;
           $(this).find('.results > span').html( code );
        });


    });
```

```js
$('.resultsbtn').click(function() {
   
        $('.items-block').each(function() {
    
            var text1 = $(this).find('.text1').val();
            var text2 = $(this).find('.text2').val();
            var text3 = $(this).find('.text3').val();
    
           var code = ' | '+ text1 +', '+ text2 +', '+ text3;
           $(this).find('.results > span').html( code );
        });
    
       
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="items-block">
  <div class="results">The Results are: <span></span></div>
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
  <div class="results">The Results are: <span></span></div>
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>
<div class="items-block">
  <div class="results">The Results are: <span></span></div>
    <label for="text1">Text 1: </label><input name="text1" type="text" class="text1" value=""/>
    <label for="text2">Text 2: </label><input name="text2" type="text" class="text2" value=""/>
    <label for="text1">Text 3: </label><input name="text3" type="text" class="text3" value=""/>
</div>

<button class="resultsbtn">View Results</button>
```

Comment: misread question - this answer is right , ou got to it before I could edit

Comment: There's a scope issue with your answer; it  gives the same result as OP.

Comment: @PeterKA, right thanks for the heads up. Updated my answer

Comment: You updated only the demo. But,  you're overwriting the previous values.

Comment: The OP wanted all 9 values outputted to the same location, as one string. You might try concatenating the values on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.resultsbtn').click(function() {
     var code = '';
     $('.items-block').each(function() {

        var text1 = $(this).find('.text1').val();
        var text2 = $(this).find('.text2').val();
        var text3 = $(this).find('.text3').val();

       code = ' | '+ text1 +', '+ text2 +', '+ text3;
    });

    $('.results > span').html( code );
});
```

input is in .items-block

Comment: The output is not as the OP desired.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to declare your `code` variable outside your `each` loop to be able to show it in the span element. Also, you need to select the `input:text` within each div.

Try this:

```
   $('.resultsbtn').click(function () {
   var code = "";   // <-----
   $('.items-block input:text').each(function () {

       var text1 = $(this).val();
       var text2 = $(this).val();
       var text3 = $(this).val();

       code += ' | ' + text1 + ', ' + text2 + ', ' + text3;
   });

   $('.results > span').html(code);
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ydep453/)

Comment: This sets the same value three times for each input, rather than each input's value for each item block. Output is `| 1, 1, 1 | 2, 2, 2 | 3, 3, 3 | 4, 4, 4 | 5, 5, 5 | 6, 6, 6 | 7, 7, 7 | 8, 8, 8 | 9, 9, 9`